# "MySQL server has gone away" followed by "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes"

Tags: php, mysql, unix, cakephp

A lot of people ask about this, but none of the previous answers solved my issue.

I'm running a CakePHP web app and every so often I get 2 errors in succession:

`MySQL server has gone away in [/var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/PDODriverTrait.php, line 159]`

followed by

`SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes`

This happens when a new record is attempted to be inserted into the DB.

After the errors the database connection still seems to be working as PHP can still read from it, but ANY new `INSERT` into the database results in another `Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes` error. The only solution at that point is to restart mySQL or the error will show up on every other `INSERT` forever.

**I have already set max_allowed_packet = 512M in my.cnf as suggested and that didn't solve the problem.**

I refuse to believe that someone is sending a packet larger than 512MB! Am I missing something? Is there some cache or queue somewhere which every so often just fills up that a restart clears and makes everything work fine again?

Comment: what is the size of your data ?

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam It's small. Got the error this morning when a user tried to register (literally a post request with 5 fields).

Comment: did you restart the MySQL? check max packet size `show variables like 'max_allowed_packet'` from mysql terminal.

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam yes `max_allowed_packet | 536870912`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug with CakePHP < 3.6.10

Fixed here: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/11668